# Why does ng-click="test()" not work but onclick="angular.element(this).scope().test()" does?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-click

I have defined an angularjs directive as follows:

```
jtApp.directive("jtWizardPage", [function () {
    return {
        require: ["^ngController", "^jtWizard"],
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: "<ng-form id='{{pageName}}' class='page' name='wizardform' ng-submit='test()' style='width:{{maxPageWidth}}px'>" +
                  "  <div ng-transclude></div>" +
                  "  <input type='submit' style='visibility:hidden;' />" +
                  "  <button type='button' onclick='console.log(angular.element(this).scope())'>debug</button>" +
                  "  <button type='button' onclick='angular.element(this).scope().test()'>works</button>" +
                  "  <button type='button' ng-click='test()'>does not work</button>" +
                  "</ng-form>",
        scope: {
            pageName: "@",
            mainHeader: "@",
            subHeader: "@"
        },
```

Can anybody tell my why the button in the template with onclick="..." works and the button with ng-click="..." does not??? Because of this problem the ng-submit seems not to work either. Shouldn't ng-click execute the expression on the same scope angular.element(this).scope() returns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have created directive with isoloated scope. the reason it works in one case and not work in another is it uses different scope. in first case the test function visible in in second not.

to get it works you should create directive with inherited (not isolated) scope or pass the test() function to isolated scope.

Comment: Thanks Anton. You are right! Thanks a lot! I had the wrong assumption that ng-click works on the same scope as the scope() method, executed on the current element, returns.

Answer (score 1):

It's because when you declared a `scope` in your directive, it's treated as isolated scope.

you can remove `scope` from your directive and then it will share the parent scope.

alternatively, i would recommend to pass an `options` object to your directive (check this plnkr example: http://plnkr.co/edit/gq3y1Z4zHs4wvp8hiiel):

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.test = function() {
    alert('clicked');
  };

  $scope.wizard_options = {
    pageName: "@",
    mainHeader: "@",
    subHeader: "@",
    test: $scope.test
  }


  $scope.label = "The Label";
})
  .directive("jtWizardPage", [

    function($scope) {
      return {
        restrict: "AEC",
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: "<div>" +
          "  <button type='button' ng-click='options.test()'>does work</button>" +
          " <pre>{{options}}</pre>" + 
          "</div>" ,
        scope: {
          options: '='
        }

      };
    }
  ]);
```

html

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <div jt-wizard-page options="wizard_options"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort!